# operator += overloading with dynamic array of polyomorphic objects

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following `Cat` class and `MegaCat` which inherits it:

```
class Cat
{
    // Class variables
    // Ct'or
    // Dt'or

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, Cat &cat)
    {
           // print Cat data
    }

 
}

class MegaCat : public Cat
{
     // Class variables
     // Ct'or
     // Dt'or
     
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, MegaCat &megacat)
    {
           // print megacatdata
    }
}
```

and suppose I have a `DB` class object that contains dynamically allocated array of pointers to `Cat` objects,
the `DB` class has the `+=` operator overloading, as follows:

```
class DB{
   private Cat ** cats;
   private int num_of_cats;


DB& DB::operator += (const Cat& cat)
{
   Cats ** temp = new Cat*[num_of_cats + 1];
   for(int i = 0 ; i < num_of_cats; i++)
   {
       temp[i] = cats[i];
   }

   temp[num_of_cats] = (Cat*)&cat;
   num_of_cats ++;
   cats = temp;

   return *this;
}

    ostream & operator << (ostream &out, DB&db)
    {
          for(int i = 0 ; i < num_of_cats; i ++)
          {
                  out << cats[i] << endl;
          }
    }
}
```

The questions that I have are:

1. How to handle the memory allocation/deallocation properly?
2. How to handle instances of `MegaCat` properly?
3. How to handle the copy to the `temp` array properly?

all of these, without the usage of vectors or any build-in resizing available.

My main:

```
DB db;
Cat *c = new Cat(...);
db += *c;
Cat *mc = new MegaCat(....)
db += *mg;

cout << db;
```

Comment: The megaCat objects are not inserted to the array properly.

Comment: I think you'll get a memory leak here. You have to free the memory occupied by the old cats array.

Comment: @ranifisch Provide a [mcve] reproducing the problem as required here please!

Comment: I would recommend you to use a container from the STL, then you don't have to deal with such low-level C things :D

Comment: 1) use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr<Cat>`, 2) use `std::unique_ptr<Cat>`, 3) use `std::vector` and no `temp` at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ editted.

Comment: @Bananenkönig I can't use STL

Comment: @ranifisch _"I can't use STL"_ Any resilient reasoning besides _Our teacher/prof told us not to_? Your code example is still [**far from a mcve**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef86de0648e67262), you should overhaul it again.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to handle the memory allocation/deallocation properly?

By following these rules:

- Delete what you new.
- Don't delete what you don't new.
- Delete each new exactly once.
- Don't lose a pointer returned by new before you delete. That's a memory leak.

Easiest way to follow these rules is to not use new directly at all. For example, instead of allocating a dynamic array, use `std::vector`.

---

> 2. How to handle instances of MegaCat properly?

Make sure that `~Cat` is virtual.

---

> suppose I have a DB class object that contains dynamically allocated array of Cat objects

Your `DB` doesn't contain an array of `Cat` objects. It contains a pointer which points to a dynamic array of pointers to `Cat` objects.

Comment: thanks for your answer. about 1, i can't use STL.
about 2. Okay.